# Displaying loading screen until static Next.js app is rendered

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to display a loading screen before the whole static page is loaded. I am using modules:export to create the static page. But I can not listen to the window load event as when NextJs executes, the window has already been loaded.

I tried using an external script using next/script, but I can't get my head around how to listen to it from inside the next app.

If anyone has any idea on how to achieve this, please help me. Thank you.

I am using the App router.

Comment: Please can you add more details like Folder Structure, 
Are you using App Router or Pages Router ?

Comment: I am using the app router. There is only one page.jsx as this is a one-page site.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

> I want to display a loading screen before the whole static page is loaded.

**Solution** :

Add `loading.js` at the root of your project.

Create `loading.js` file (this name is according to NextJS conventions, dont change).

`loading.js` file at `app\loading.js`:

```
export default function Loading() {
  return <p>Please wait while Loading...</p>
}
```

**Please Read :**

1. **loading.js** : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/loading

> ***If you still have any doubts, leave a comment.***

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this loading screen works when we navigate to a page from another page, right? My app does not have any routes or navigation, there is only one single page and one single route. I need to show the loading screen when someone first visits the site.